# Mostrar uma coluna com String no table view onde o campo da classe model é boolean - javaFX

Tags: javafx, java-11

Boa tarde, pessoal!

Estou estudando javaFX e estou criando uma aplicação simples, estava indo bem até me deparar com o seguinte problema: tenho uma classe model 'Usuario' que pode pode ou não ter privilégio de administrador, o problema ocorre quando listo os usuários em uma table view gostaria que no coluna do campo correspondente apareça "SIM" ou "NÃO" ao invés de true/false. Tentei pelo toString() da classe model mas não funcionou, segue a imagem da tabela:
[image: A coluna ADM quero que apareça sim ou não]

meu código que carrega a tabela:

```
        public void carregarTabela(List<Usuario> usuarios) {
        
        colUser.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Usuario, String>("user"));
        colSenha.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Usuario, String>("senha"));               
        colAdm.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Usuario,String >("admin"));
        tabelaUsuarios.getItems().setAll(usuarios);             
    }
```

Abaixo o toString da classe model:

```
    @Override
public String toString() {
    String admin = null;
    if(isAdmin()) {
        admin="SIM";
    }admin="NÃO";
    return "Usuario [user=" + user + ", senha=" + senha + ", admin=" + admin + "]";
}
```

Desde já agradeço quem puder me ajudar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando o cellfactory na coluna desejada

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Usuario, Boolean> colAdm;


colAdm.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Usuario, Boolean>, 
    TableCell<Usuario, Boolean>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<Usuario, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Usuario, Boolean> tableColumn) {
            return new TableCell<>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setText(null);
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        Usuario usuario = getTableRow().getItem();
                        if(usuario != null) {
                            setText(usuario.isAdmin() ? "SIM" : "NÃO");
                        } else {
                            setText(null);
                            setGraphic(null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    });
```

Comment: Cassio, muito obrigado! Era justamente o que precisava!